# Sum of numbers in a Python list except 13 and numbers after it

Tags: python

Return the sum of the numbers in the array, returning 0 for an empty array. Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count and numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count.

```
def sum13(nums):
  if nums == []:
    return 0
  sum=0
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i] == 13:
      break
  else:
    sum = sum+nums[i]
  return sum
```

The above code is failing only at:

1. sum13([1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 13]) → 4 while my answer is 3 (how 4?)
2. sum13([13, 1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 13]) → 3  while my answer is 0 (again, how is 3 correct if there are no numbers before 13?)
   Please explain the logic and what I've done wrong.

Comment: what do you think will happen when they reach [first] 13 in your list and you hit `break` statement? As to "explain the logic" - it's your logic, you should be able to explain it :-)

Comment: Well, your program does what you wanted it to do. Is this question about the exercise itself? Either the test-data is wrong, or the exercise question is unclear.

Comment: "Return the sum ..." - What makes you think you can command us?

Comment: Your result for case 1 is **not** 3 but 0.

Comment: @superbrain No, it's 3. I've found the fix though. Thanks

Comment: @BharathKalyan No, [it's 0](https://repl.it/repls/EdibleDarkmagentaCommercialsoftware#main.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers that come immediately after 13, not ALL the numbers after 13.

```py
def sum13(nums):
  if nums == []:
    return 0
  sum=0
  i = 0
  while i <= len(nums): #change this to a while loop so we can skip numbers
    if nums[i] == 13:
      i+=1 # if it's 13 we skip an extra number
    else:
      sum = sum+nums[i]
    i+=1 # this always increments the counter, but then on 13 we are now incrementing twice

  return sum


print(sum13([1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 13]))
```

Comment: a small correction in your code: In the if block, for skipping the number after a 13, it should be i += 2

Comment: @BharathKalyan if you make it i += 2, then you need to put the lower i+=1 inside of the else. I specifically left it as 1 since it's already being added to at the bottom. That's what the comment 'this always increments the counter, but then on 13 we are now incrementing twice' is about

Comment: Oh, right, sorry. Got it. I used a for block and you used while which is why I had to make it i+=2.

Comment: @BharathKalyan yea I usually am a for loop type person, but when you start to have more rules around manipulating the counter, in my experience, it's easier with a while loop. But really, either way is valid. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers "immediately after a 13" means that any number directly following a 13 in the array is ignored. For example, in [1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 13], the 2 after the 13 is ignored, but the 1 after that 2 counts.

Answer (score 0):

If you´re surfing through stacks trying to find some elegant solution, here´s mine:

```
def sum13(nums):

  if nums == 0:
    return 0
  soma = 0
  i = 0
  
  while i < len(nums):  
    if nums[i] == 13:
      i += 2
      continue
    else: 
      soma += nums[i]
      i += 1
  return soma
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def damned_13(nums):
      for i in nums:
            if i == 13:
                  return sum(nums[:nums.index(13)])
      return sum(nums)
print(damned_13([1, 2, 2, 1, 13, 55]))
```

or

```py
def damned_13(nums):
      if nums.count(13) == 1:
            return sum(nums[:nums.index(13)])
      return sum(nums)
print(damned_13([1, 2, 2, 1, 13, 55]))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=['1','2','13','2','1','13']
b=a.index('13')
a=a[:b]
a=list(map(int,a))
print(sum(a))
```